# Error [false] al hacer una consulta (MySQL - PHP - PHPMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

mi consulta está al final.

```
<?php

$usu = $_REQUEST["usu"];
$con = $_REQUEST["con"];


$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql","android");    

$res = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from profesor
where usuario='$usu' and contra='$con'")or die(mysqli_error($res));    

/*'".mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $usu)."'*/

$q = "select * from profesor where usuario = '$usu' and contra = '$con'"."   <br/>";

echo "ESTO SALE DE LA VARIABLE sq Y CONTIENE --> $q";

if($res == null){
 echo "No hay nadie con el usuario y contraseña insertado";
 }else{
 echo "Sí hay alguien con el usuario y contraseña insertado"."<br/>";
 }


$datos = array();

foreach ((array) $res as $row){
    $datos[]=$row;
}

 $final = json_encode($datos);

echo $final;


?>
```

Esta es mi BD actual, esta bd es de prueba nada más, para practicar, así que lo puedo mostrar tranquilamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la siguiente imagen es esta: La primera linea es para ver si existe alguien con el usuario y contraseña insertado, y correctamente me sale que existe. La segunda es el if que hice para ver si hay registro encontrado en la variable "q". Esta sentencia que se me muestra en mi navegador "select * from profesor where usuario = 'gezer' and contra = 'hola'" lo he ejecutado en phpmyadmin y me muestra el campo correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me haya dejado entender, ahora mi consulta es porque en la linea 3 me sale: [], como si estuviera vacío el arreglo, creo que me tendría que salir los datos de la persona con ese usuario y contraseña.

Comment: `mysql_error()`  != `mysqli_error($conexion)` estás mezclano `mysql` y `mysqli`.... cuéntanos cual es el error con solo `HERE ERROR` no nos ayuda mucho

Comment: Deberías leer sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código que compartes contiene vulnerabilidades de seguridad y puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL por lo que no debería estar en entornos de producción de cara al público.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta. Mira a ver si te puede ser de utilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, nunca de los nuncas hagas consultas a DB con datos provenientes del usuario sin validarlos y sanarlos ya que así como lo tienes eres vulnerable a inyección sql.

Segundo,

```
die('HERE ERROR!!!!'.mysql_error());
```

Estás mezclando la extensión mysqli con la obsoleta mysql, [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-error.php) la referencia que es en extremo recomendable que le des un vistazo. Lo mejor es que uses **mysqli_error:**

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

(Ejemplo extraído de la [documentación oficial](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)).

Tercero, puede que el error sea porque tu sentencia devuelve null. **¿Cómo comprobarlo?**

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$query = "select * from profesor
where usuario='$usu' and contraseña='$con'"; 

echo $query;
```

Te imprimirá la consulta que haces a mysql, entonces la copias y la ejecutas en Phpmyadmin directamente en la parte que dice *SQL*. Si está mal la consulta allí lo sabrás, si está bien entonces es error de tu código, pero creo que lo más probable sea del SELECT.

Comentas cómo te fue.

***Edición después de saber que la consulta es correcta***

El array imprime vacío porque en efecto, nunca se le agrega nada. ¿Por qué? parece que el modo en que haces el foreach.

Sólo para comprender lo que sucede, para testear haz lo siguiente:

```
var_dump($res);
```

Te aparecerá que es un resource, o sea un resultado de una consulta. el siguiente paso es pasar su contenido a una estructura de datos como un array.

Para ello prueba sustituir el foreach por lo siguiente:

```
// Segundo parámetro MYSQLI_ASSOC te dará un array asociativo
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Te dará array numérico
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

// Para que veas el valor final
var_dump($row);
```

Y creo que con eso basta. Parece que necesitas una repasada a Php con Mysqli, no sé se permita hacer esto, pero entra a mi perfil de aquí y ve a mis enlaces, yo hago tutoriales y cursos sobre estos temas, te pueden servir.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, lo aprecio mucho, recién comienzo en este lenguaje, ya me tomaré el tiempo para investigar lo de las inyecciones sql acá en php.
He aplicado las soluciones que me planteaste y parecen haber solucionado parte del problema..

He editado mi post con lo que tengo actualmente, te agradecería muchísimo si lo revisaras nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Visto que la sentencia sql te la devuelve bien, creo que el problema lo tienes a la hora de recoger cada una de las filas de la consulta. Para ello, podrías usar la función [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

```
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    print_r($fila);
}
```

A la función [`mysqli_connect`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) podrías pasarle también el nombre de la base de datos como parámetro:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql","android");
```

Por lo tanto, podrías eliminar la función `mysqli_select_db` de tu programa.

Comment: La sugerencia sería **Podría** en lugar de **Debería** ya que es valida la opción de realizar la selección de la BD como la hace el OP.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Vale, ahora lo modifico. Realmente nunca había visto `mysqli_connect` con tres parámetros, de hecho busqué en la documentación de `mysqli_select_db` para ver si cambiaba en algo e incluso aquí utilizan `mysqli_connect` con cuatro parámetros. Por eso pensaba que no se podía realizar únicamente con tres. Muchas gracias por la aclaración.